# how to add CSS style by javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am new to javascript. try on changing the CSS style by javascript.
I would like to add the style for the a tag under the specific p tag(.font_8), and the a tag already has some style.

the style I try to do is this, but I would like to add the style by javascript.

```
<style>
.font_8 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted currentColor;
}
.font_8 a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid currentColor;
}
</style>


 <p class="font_8" style="font-size:16px">text text text text<br>
        <span style="text-decoration:underline"><a href="URL-link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">link link link</a></span>（text）
      </p>



    <script>
        function getElements(){
    var font_8 = document.getElementsByClassName('font_8');
    var elements = font_8.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var len = elements.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        elements[i].style = {
            textDecoration: 'none',
            color: 'red',
            borderBottom: '2px dotted currentColor',
            }
    }
}
function getElements(){
    var font_8 = document.getElementsByClassName('font_8');
    var elements = font_8.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var len = elements.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        elements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        elements[i].style.borderBottom= '2px solid currentColor';
    }
                           )
    }
}
      </script>
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong? I get some JavaScript errors that you might be able to debug.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71302817/edit) to explain what you expect to happen vs what is actually happening? Also, check your browser's dev-tools console for errors. You have several syntax related ones that will prevent your code from ever running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is necessarily what you are going for. But I got the event listener adding the red line under the p tag and it adds the constant styles as well. I didn't know if you were trying to add it to the font_8 or the a tag since you were getting both of them before each loop.

I also added an `mouseout` event to get rid of the solid line.

```js
const styles = {
  textDecoration: 'none',
  color: 'red',
  borderBottom: '2px dotted currentColor',
}

function getElements() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('font_8');
  var len = elements.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      Object.keys(styles).forEach((key)=>{
        elements[i].style[key]=styles[key]
      })
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++){
      elements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        elements[i].style.borderBottom= '2px solid currentColor';
      })
      elements[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        Object.keys(styles).forEach((key)=>{
          elements[i].style[key]=styles[key]
        })
      })
  }
}

getElements()
```

```html
<p class="font_8" style="font-size:16px">text text text text
  <br>
  <span style="text-decoration:underline">
    <a href="URL-link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">link link link</a>
  </span>
  (text）  
</p>
```

I didn't know if you wanted to bring back the dotted or not, however. If you dont want to bring back the dotted line, you can just use the Object.keys method and put it in the mouseout function like:

```
elements[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  elements[i].style.borderBottom= '';
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
The one I want to try on is to add the style at the a tag under the specific p(class="font_8") tag.
the code that you help is for the whole p tag, is a bit different from what i expected.

thank you for reminding about mouseout. yes i need it.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace all your `len[i]` with `elements[i]` (the `len` variable stores a number, the `elements` variable stores a list).

On line 14, the `,` should be an  `=` I think (if you want to update the style of `element[i]`) :

```js
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        elements[i].style = {
          textDecoration: 'none',
          color: 'red',
          borderBottom: '2px dotted currentColor',
        }
      }
```

And missing a closing bracket on line 27-28 (to close the `for` loop).